# zk MVC null check text box value data-bind annotation

Tags: zk

My page has text-boxes whose value attribute annotated as `@{bean.innerbean.prop}`. Here if inner bean obj is null , it throws null exception since when it does "nullobj.prop" evaluation.

I'm using MVC 'not MVVM'. How to do null check on  `bean.innerbean`  then load or save value from `bean.innerbean.prop`.

'bean' obj I set it as page scope.it has other props as name,tooltip etc which obviously work well to other respective annotated components....
   Please let me know is the way to do "empty", `== null` on `@{……}`  ..

Im using annotation(in MVC long since in my app) to bind user entered-value to be saved on the object as well loading it on `AnnotateDataBinder.loadAlll()` method being invoke from `AnnotateDataBinderInit` class `doAfterCompose()`. My question anyway to do null check on the annotated bean value..... EL Expression evaluated once on the page load phase thereafter it wont work

Comment: Give me working fiddle with your `nullpointer` and I give you a solution

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you are using MVC you use the wrong annotation.

`${}` is used for [el expressions](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/UI_Composing/ZUML/EL_Expressions), while `@{}` is used for [data binding](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/MVVM/Data_Binding), witch is MVVM.

So if you use the correct expression you can do :

```
${empty bean.innerbean?'empty':bean.innerbean.prop}
```